# WiX ICE64: The directory XX is in the user profile

Tags: wix

I have checked the answers here and the blog post at http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2007/4/27/how-to-create-an-uninstall-shortcut-and-pass-all-the/, but I just cannot see what I am missing. I believe I am using MfgStartMenuFolder correctly. The error is at:

```
<Directory Id="MfgStartMenuFolder" Name="!(bind.property.Manufacturer)" />
```

In my main fragment I have:

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
  <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
   <Directory Id="ManufacturerFolder" Name="!(bind.property.Manufacturer)" >
      <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="!(bind.property.ProductName)" />
    </Directory>
  </Directory>

 <Directory Id="ProgramMenuFolder" >
  <Directory Id="MfgStartMenuFolder" Name="!(bind.property.Manufacturer)" />
 </Directory>
</Directory>
```

In my fragment for Start Menu folder objects I have:

```
<DirectoryRef Id="MfgStartMenuFolder" >
  <Component Id="ApplicationShortcut" Guid="MY-GUID" >
    <Shortcut Id="ApplicationStartMenuShortcut"
              Name="!(bind.property.ProductName)"
              Description="Find Files (Reasonably) Fast"
              Directory="MfgStartMenuFolder"
              Target="[INSTALLFOLDER]\FinderOfFiles.exe"
              WorkingDirectory="INSTALLFOLDER"
              Icon="MyShortcutIcon" />

    <RemoveFolder Id="RemoveMfgStartMenuFolder"
                  Directory="MfgStartMenuFolder"
                  On="uninstall" />

    <RegistryValue Root="HKCU"
        Key="Software\[Manufacturer]\[ProductName]\ProgramMenuShortcut"
        Name="installed"
        Type="integer"
        Value="1"
        KeyPath="yes" />
  </Component>
</DirectoryRef>
```

I am using WiX 3.11 and not using any add-ons like Wax.

Comment: The full error message is: ICE64: The directory MfgStartMenuFolder is in the user profile but is not listed in the RemoveFile Table.

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote the whole sections, so this issue is moot.